# Pandas: Add a new column in a data frame based on a value in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames one with a userId, and gender and another data frame that has online activities of these users.

First Data Frame `(df1)`

```
userId, gender
001, F
002, M
003, F
004, M
005, M
006, M
```

Second data frame `(df2)`

```
userId, itemClicked, ItemBought, date
001, 123182, 123212, 02/02/2016
003, 234256, 123182, 05/02/2016
005, 986834, 234256, 04/19/2016
004, 787663, 787663, 05/12/2016
020, 465738, 465738, 03/20/2016
004, 787223, 787663, 07/12/2016
```

I want to add gender column to the second data frame by looking up the first data frame based on the userId. df2 might have multiple rows per user since its a click data where same user may have click multiple items.

This is very easy to do in MySql but I am trying to figure out to do it in pandas.

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    user_id = row['userId']
    if user_id in df1['userId']:
        t = df1.loc[df1['userId'] == user_id]
        pdb.set_trace()
```

Is this the pandas way to so such a task?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
print (df1)
   userId gender
0       1      F
1       2      M
2       3      F
3       4      M
4       5      M
5       6      M

print (df2)
   userId  itemClicked  ItemBought        date
0       1       123182      123212  02/02/2016
1       3       234256      123182  05/02/2016
2       5       986834      234256  04/19/2016
3       4       787663      787663  05/12/2016
4      20       465738      465738  03/20/2016
5       4       787223      787663  07/12/2016
```

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2['gender'] = df2.userId.map(df1.set_index('userId')['gender'].to_dict())

print (df2)
   userId  itemClicked  ItemBought        date gender
0       1       123182      123212  02/02/2016      F
1       3       234256      123182  05/02/2016      F
2       5       986834      234256  04/19/2016      M
3       4       787663      787663  05/12/2016      M
4      20       465738      465738  03/20/2016    NaN
5       4       787223      787663  07/12/2016      M
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and left join, parameter `on` can be omit if only column `gender` is same in both DataFrames:

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left')

print (df)
   userId  itemClicked  ItemBought        date gender
0       1       123182      123212  02/02/2016      F
1       3       234256      123182  05/02/2016      F
2       5       986834      234256  04/19/2016      M
3       4       787663      787663  05/12/2016      M
4      20       465738      465738  03/20/2016    NaN
5       4       787223      787663  07/12/2016      M
```

**Timings**:

```
#len(df2) = 600k
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

def f(df1,df2):
    df2['gender'] = df2.userId.map(df1.set_index('userId')['gender'].to_dict())
    return df2


In [43]: %timeit f(df1,df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.2 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit (pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left'))
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is this a good approach when dealing with large data frames.10million records?

Comment: df2 might have same user more than once since its a click / transaction data. Merge might be problematic right.

Comment: I add timings, `map` solution is the fastest.

Comment: Looks like merge is not possible because second data frame doesn't have the gender column. is it possible to do something like this df2['gender'] = NULL, and then do the merge

Comment: I think there is no problem, because it is same as `(pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left', on='userId'))` - it is left join on column `userId`

Comment: map doesn't work when the data has multiple entries for the same userId. Since index can only be created on primary key, I get error Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects.

Comment: @Milan - absolutely agree.

Answer (score 1):

If user_id is the index you can just use :

```
df2.join(df1)
```

Comment: second data frame have multiple records per same user so its hard to create an index for that data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
   for ind,r in df2.iterrows():
      if r['userId']==row['userId']:
         df2.set_value(ind,'Gender',row['gender'])
         break
```